# Create a new instance of a Class given an instance in Python

Tags: python, oop

In Python, if I have an object, say `x`, then how do I create a new object `y` so that `x` and `y` are of the same class?

In Java, the code I want would look something like this:

```
Object y = x.getClass().newInstance();
```

Comment: Keep in mind that class is a flexible concept in Python, given the ability to use custom metaclasses and descriptors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably do something like:

```
y = x.__class__()
```

or

```
y = type(x)()  #New style classes only
```

And, if you're wondering how to make a new style class, all you need to do is inherit from `object` (or use python 3.x)

Comment: type won't work for old style classes. Also, this probably won't work for metaclasses.

Comment: Thanks for the comment about old style classes (I *never* use them, so I didn't think of that.)  As far as `metaclass`es are concerned, I don't use those either, so I can't help with that one.  It's good to know where my solution might fail though.  Thanks for pointing that out too.

Comment: I can't see why there's a problem with metaclasses. The problem to me is that you're calling the constructor without arguments and it may require some.

Comment: Like the OP's question, this assumes the constructor requires no arguments.

Comment: @JBernardo -- Of course it is assumed here that `__init__` recieves no arguments (other than the obligatory `self`).  I would assume you would have the same problem in `Java`?

Comment: I was assuming Java creates a raw object of that class (Not initialized) because if it was initialized probably the keyword `new` would be used (not a Java expert here)

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same as in Java:

```
y = x.__class__()
```